# Pass to ngclass enum string value

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created an `enum` to organize my new component styles, I need to write multiple ng class expressions or dynamically pass directly to the element call. How can I directly call on element?

**button-types.ts**

```
export enum ButtonTypes {
   Primary = 'button-primary',
   Secondary = 'button-secondary',
   Terciary = 'button-terciary',
   IconButton = 'button-icon',
}
```

**bo-button.component.html**

```
<button [ngClass]="type">
  <i [ngClass]="icon"></i>
  {{ label }}
</button>
```

**bo-button.componrny**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonTypes } from './shared/button-types';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-bo-button',
  templateUrl: './bo-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bo-button.component.scss']
})   

export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public type: ButtonTypes;
  @Input() public icon: string;
  @Input() public label: string;
  @Input() public arrow: string;

  constructor() {
  }    
  ngOnInit() {
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign the `ButtonTypes` enum definition to a property of the parent component, you can use that property in the template for data binding with literal enum values. Data binding with properties having enum values also works, like the `myButtonType` example below.

```
import { ButtonTypes } from './button-types.enum';
...
export class AppComponent {

  ButtonTypes = ButtonTypes;             // <-- Allows to use enum literals in template
  myButtonType = ButtonTypes.Secondary;  // <-- Specific enum value for binding
}
```

```
<lib-bo-button [type]="ButtonTypes.Terciary" label="My terciary button"></lib-bo-button>
<lib-bo-button [type]="myButtonType" label="My button"></lib-bo-button>
```

The appropriate class style will be applied, assuming that it is defined for each `ButtonTypes` value:

```
button.button-primary {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

button.button-secondary {
  background-color: green;
}

button.button-terciary {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

button.button-icon {
  background-color: red;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhmx1c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.